# Dictionary that covert a string to OTAN phonetic alphabet

Tags: python, dictionary

The user enter a word that which is converted to OTAN phonetic alphabet.

I have to use a dictionary and  I put this code:

```
def otan():


    dictionary = {'A':'Alpha', 'B':'Bravo','C':'Charlie', 'D':'Delta', 'E':'Echo', 'F':'Foxtrot', 'G':'Golf', 'I':'India', 'J':'Juliet', 'K':'Kilo', 'L':'Lima', 'M':'Mike', 'N':'November', 'O':'Oscar', 'P':'Papa', 'Q':'Quebec', 'R':'Romeo', 'S':'Sierra', 'T':'Tango', 'U':'Uniform', 'V':'Victor', 'W':'Whiskey', 'X':'Xray', 'Y':'Yankee', 'Z':'Zulu'}
    input('Enter a word:')

otan()
```

I enter a word for exemple GH

But appears this : `NameError: name 'GH' is not defined`

I dont understand the error because the dictionary includes the letter G and H

Comment: yes but they would be  two keys not one  and actually H is not in your dict

Comment: Please post complete code that reproduces problem.

Comment: The error dont exist, but the result is incorrect because python print GH not Golf Hotel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access each keys separately and use `raw_input`, GH would be two keys not one

```
dictionary = {'A':'Alpha', 'B':'Bravo','C':'Charlie', 'D':'Delta', 'E':'Echo', 'F':'Foxtrot', 'G':'Golf',"H":"Hotel", 'I':'India', 'J':'Juliet', 'K':'Kilo', 'L':'Lima', 'M':'Mike', 'N':'November', 'O':'Oscar', 'P':'Papa', 'Q':'Quebec', 'R':'Romeo', 'S':'Sierra', 'T':'Tango', 'U':'Uniform', 'V':'Victor', 'W':'Whiskey', 'X':'Xray', 'Y':'Yankee', 'Z':'Zulu'}

inp = raw_input('Enter a word:')
print(" ".join(map(dictionary.get,inp)))
Enter a word:GH
Golf Hotel
```

Answer (score 1):

#python3

```
prompt_response = str(input("What's your name?"))

dict = {'A':'Alpha', 'B':'Bravo','C':'Charlie', 'D':'Delta', 'E':'Echo', 'F':'Foxtrot', 'G':'Golf',"H":"Hotel", 'I':'India', 'J':'Juliet', 'K':'Kilo', 'L':'Lima', 'M':'Mike', 'N':'November', 'O':'Oscar', 'P':'Papa', 'Q':'Quebec', 'R':'Romeo', 'S':'Sierra', 'T':'Tango', 'U':'Uniform', 'V':'Victor', 'W':'Whiskey', 'X':'Xray', 'Y':'Yankee', 'Z':'Zulu'}

sDict = {x.upper(): dict[x.upper()] for x in prompt_response}

print(sDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
def otan(word):
  dictionary = {'A':'Alpha', 'B':'Bravo','C':'Charlie', 'D':'Delta', 'E':'Echo', 'F':'Foxtrot', 'G':'Golf', 'I':'India', 'J':'Juliet', 'K':'Kilo', 'L':'Lima', 'M':'Mike', 'N':'November', 'O':'Oscar', 'P':'Papa', 'Q':'Quebec', 'R':'Romeo', 'S':'Sierra', 'T':'Tango', 'U':'Uniform', 'V':'Victor', 'W':'Whiskey', 'X':'Xray', 'Y':'Yankee', 'Z':'Zulu'}
  phon = [dictionary[w] for w in word]
  return ' '.join(phon)

word = raw_input('Enter word: ')
print otan(word)
```

BTW. If you want to enter word `GH` in your `dictionary` there is no `H`

Answer (score -2):

You are using Python2, so you need to use `raw_input('Enter word:')`.

Next, when you get the word from the user, you need to fetch *for each letter*, the corresponding word from your dictionary:

```
d = {'A':'Alpha', 'B':'Bravo','C':'Charlie', 'D':'Delta', 'E':'Echo', 'F':'Foxtrot', 'G':'Golf', 'I':'India', 'J':'Juliet', 'K':'Kilo', 'L':'Lima', 'M':'Mike', 'N':'November', 'O':'Oscar', 'P':'Papa', 'Q':'Quebec', 'R':'Romeo', 'S':'Sierra', 'T':'Tango', 'U':'Uniform', 'V':'Victor', 'W':'Whiskey', 'X':'X-ray', 'Y':'Yankee', 'Z':'Zulu'}

word = raw_input('Enter word:')
for letter in word:
   print(d.get(letter.upper()), end='')
```

A simpler way to write the same loop is:

```
word = raw_input('Enter word:')
print(' '.join(d.get(letter.upper(), letter) for letter in word))
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> word = raw_input('Enter word:')
Enter word:PYTHON
>>> print(' '.join(d.get(letter.upper(), letter) for letter in word))
Papa Yankee Tango H Oscar November
```

You are missing `H` in your original dictionary, which is why it is showing as is.

Comment: Ok but how i can separete the final result for example, the user enter the word PYTHON all together and I want that the result will be Papa Yankee Tango Hotel Oscar November. (separate by a space)