# Replace each letter of a string with words from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to replace letters in a string with words from the dictionary. For example: home should output 'Hotel', 'Oscar', 'Mike', 'Echo'. However if I type rain, it outputs `raiNovember`. Below is my code. Could someone please help me figure out why it is not working? TIA

I am new to Python and I am trying to learn dictionaries.

Comment: Do `sentence = sentence.replace(...)`. Strings are immutable, calling `replace` creates a new string.

Comment: Quite similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26324038/1435475)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to store the word corresponding to each letter into a list. You can append each word that corresponds to the letter as you loop over the letters to this list, and you will have what you are looking for at the end.

Modified your code to do this, it should now output what you want when you print to console.

```py
letters_to_words = {
    'a' : "Alpha", 'b' : "Bravo", 'c' : "Charlie", 'd' : "Delta",
    'e' : "Echo", 'f' : "Foxtrot", 'g' : "Golf", 'h' : "Hotel",
    'i' : "India", 'j' : "Juliet", 'k' : "Kilo", 'l' : "Lima",
    'm' : "Mike", 'n' : "November", 'o' : "Oscar", 'p' : "Papa",
    'q' : "Quebec", 'r' : "Romeo", 's' : "Sierra", 't' : "Tango",
    'u' : "Uniform", 'v' : "Victor", 'w' : "Whiskey", 'x' : "X-Ray",
    'y' : "Yankee", 'z' : "Zulu"
}
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
words = []
for i in sentence:
    word = letters_to_words[i]
    words.append(word)

print(words)
```

Comment: `sentence.lower()` needs to assign the lowered string `sentence = sentence.lower()` because strings are *immutable* so that the new lowered string is assigned (in this case) to the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'rain' has 4 letters.
Therefore your loop will be executed Four times.

1. First, run : *r* is replaced by Romeo, hence words= **Romeo** ain
2. Second, run : *a* is replaced by Alpha, hence words=r **Alpha** in
3. Third, run :  *i* is replaced by India, hence words = ra **India** n
4. Last, run : *n* is replaced by November, hence words= rai **November**

### Since 'words' was not initialized to null i.e, words = "".

Therefore the recent value of words is printed i.e, raiNovember

The correct code is given below:

```
letters_to_words = {
    'a' : "Alpha", 'b' : "Bravo", 'c' : "Charlie", 'd' : "Delta",
    'e' : "Echo", 'f' : "Foxtrot", 'g' : "Golf", 'h' : "Hotel",
    'i' : "India", 'j' : "Juliet", 'k' : "Kilo", 'l' : "Lima",
    'm' : "Mike", 'n' : "November", 'o' : "Oscar", 'p' : "Papa",
    'q' : "Quebec", 'r' : "Romeo", 's' : "Sierra", 't' : "Tango",
    'u' : "Uniform", 'v' : "Victor", 'w' : "Whiskey", 'x' : "X-Ray",
    'y' : "Yankee", 'z' : "Zulu"
}
sentence = input("Enter input: ")
sentence.lower()
words = ""
for i in sentence:
    words += letters_to_words[i]+" "   

print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary part seems to work mostly, but some issues are not really addressed by the other answers:

- In any case separate input and output and do no try to change your input string while iterating. Replacing *rain* by *romeoain* and still knowing where to continue is not that easy.
- Keep the replacement parts separated in case of further processing (language output) is required
- Be prepared for non-alphabetic input, where dictionary look-up throws `KeyError` exception
- Use helpful contructs offered by Python instead of what you may be familiar with already.

So my proposal for the processing part is:

```
    word_list = [letters_to_words.get(c, "?") for c in sentence.lower()]
    print ", ".join(word_list)
```